# AWS: Linking static website to domain name on Route53 of different AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53, website-hosting

I've been having issues in linking a *static website* hosted on `S3 bucket` in one AWS account to a custom domain name regsitered on `Route53` on another AWS account. Is it not possible to do such types of linking, where the **S3 bucket and the Route53 are on two different AWS accounts**? If so, what could be the  solution for my case!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An A-record alias is needed at the zone apex (e.g. example.com) but not for subdomains (e.g. www.example.com, because here, you can use a CNAME instead) when hosting a site on S3, and this doesn't work across AWS accounts.

However... there's one word in your question that leads me to believe the following solution may be useful.  The word is "registered."

> custom domain name regsitered on Route53 on another AWS account

If the domain is *registered* by the Route 53 registrar under one AWS account, you can still create a Route 53 hosted zone on a *different* AWS account -- the one with the bucket -- and then change the authoritative nameservers in the Route 53 console in the first account.  This delegates operational control to the second account.

Create a hosted zone for the domain in account 2 (the same one as the bucket).  Make a note of the 4 NS records that Route 53 assigns to the hosted zone.  Do not change them.  Just note what they are.  Configure this hosted zone with the appropriate A record alias pointing to the bucket.

Then, in account 1 (where you registered the domain) in the Route 53 console, click "Registered Domains."

Select your domain.

Choose "add/edit name servers."

Enter the values for the Route 53 name servers that were assigned by Route 53 for the new hosted zone in account 2.

Wait a few minutes.

Test.

It will probably take at least 15 minutes for this to start working (it can theoretically take 48 hours but this is very unlikely), and after this, you can remove the hosted zone from account 1.  Its configuration is ignored, anyway, if you don't.

Route 53 will continue to bill account 1 for the annual registration, but will bill account 2 for the hosted zone.  Neither account will be charged for the DNS queries, but account 2 will be billed $0.00 for them, since the queries are against an alias pointing to S3, and in such cases, queries are free.

Answer (score 2):

This should work just fine. It doesn't matter that the Route 53 entry points to a bucket in a different account.

You should follow these directions: [Example: Setting Up a Static Website Using a Custom Domain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html) with a few changes...

Basically:

- **Create a bucket** with a name that matches your domain name (eg `images.example.com`) and activate **Static Website Hosting**
- Copy the **Endpoint** presented. It will look like: `images.example.com.s3-website.amazonaws.com`
- In Route 53 (in any account), **create a Hosted Zone** for your domain (eg `example.com`)
- Within the Hosted Zone, **create a Record Set** for `images.example.com` of type `CNAME`. Then enter the Static Website Hosting **Endpoint** that was copied above.

Then test the domain. For example, `images.example.com/foo.jpg` should return the `foo.jpg` file from your bucket.

It is not possible to use `Alias=YES` for a Static Website in a different account.

Comment: I did try what u had mentioned.But I don't see my website in the list presented.

Comment: Ah! You're correct, it won't show up in the list. I'll update the instructions.

Comment: Originally, I had the domain pointed to an EC2 instance. So I am removing the reference & replacing the Alias target of the root domain's A record as example.com (for eg) and creating another www.example.com A record with the copied endpoint as the target value. But I get a "site can't be reached" error!

Comment: Also, when I try to enter the endpoint as the Alias value ,I get an "Invalid value" error and the record set is not created.

Comment: Okay, so you can't use `Alias=Yes` for a different account. In that case, just use a `CNAME` record pointing to `http://images.example.com.s3-website.amazonaws.com`

Comment: So I do not have an A record at all ? But when I try to create a CNAME for example.com, I get this - RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name example.com. is not permitted at apex in zone example.com.

Comment: Correct. You will need to `CNAME` to the URL `images.example.com.s3-website.amazonaws.com` (without the `http://` -- my bad).

Comment: I did not add in the `http://`. I get the error that I posted in my previous comment

Comment: Ah, yes! `CNAME` is only permitted in a sub-domain (eg `www.` or `images.`). The way around this is to use `Alias=Yes`, but that appears to only work if the Route 53 configuration is in the same account as the S3 bucket. See: [Choosing Between Alias and Non-Alias Resource Record Sets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html)